# Получение пути файла в assets

Tags: java, android, html

Нужно получить путь до style.css и чтобы файл видел локальные файлы шрифты картинки.
Хочу вставить путь сюда

```
String text = "<html><head>"
                        + "<link href=\"file:///android_asset/style.css\">"
//                       + "<style type=\"text/css\">"+textr+"</style>"
//                        + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #c1c1c1; background-color: #303030;}</style>"
                        + "</head>"
                        + "<body>"
                        + elWeb
                        + "</body></html>";
```

Писал так file:///android_asset/style.css ,  не работает (но с сайта берет стиль) 
Сейчас использую

```
InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("style.css");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            String textr = new String(buffer);
```

Но это мне не подходит

Comment: Вы это в WebView грузите? Подозреваю, что через loadData. Попробуйте через loadDataWithBaseURL, указав "file:///android_asset" в качестве baseURL. [rtfm](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: @YuraIvanov , да спасибо огромное. Работает, а не знаете у меня в в html есть ссылки так как базовая file:///android_asset они не откроются можно ли как то перенаправить.Тк как я использую jsoup ссылки могут менятся

Comment: @YuraIvanov , Ответе на вопрос, или закрыть тему. Данный ответ решает мою проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы воспринимались относительные ссылки на локальные файлы, в частности на файлы в assets необходимо загружать страницу с помощью `loadDataWithBaseURL`, указывая базовый url, в частности для assets:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset", html,...)
```

ЗЫ Если ссылки ведут на другие сервера, то их придется поменять а абсолютные на тот сервер, где находится ресурс.
ЗЗЫ Вполне возможно есть другие варианты решения оригинальной задачи, например, инъекция локальных файлов методами javascript'а...

Comment: спасибо еще раз, этот вопрос я тоже решил